# Asccending order by column name using cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

```
Android Studio 0.4.6
```

Hello,

I have the following function that should get the rows of the database in ASC order based on the column name. However it just gets the rows in the order that they are listed in the database.

So it should be in alphabetical order for names in the database.

I think my cursor query is correct, as in the debugger the cursor value is:

```
SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, name, phone, email FROM friends ORDER BY name ASC
```

Which is what I want. I then set my cursor to the first row and loop over over them until I get to the last row.

However, it doesn't display in the alphabetical for name.

```
private void loadDB() {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(FriendContract.TABLE,
                new String[] {FriendContract.Column.ID, FriendContract.Column.NAME, FriendContract.Column.PHONE, FriendContract.Column.EMAIL},
                null, null, null, null, FriendContract.Column.NAME + " ASC");

        /* Check if database is empty */
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            /* There are no rows to load - so just return */
            Log.d(TAG, "loadDB() cursor.getCount() == 0. There are no rows, just just refresh listview");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }

        /* Clear all items from array list -
            we are going to fill this with the content of the database */
        friendsList.clear();
        Friend friend;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            friend = new Friend();
            friend.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            friend.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            friend.setPhone(cursor.getString(2));
            friend.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
            /* Add this to the list of friends */
            friendsList.add(friend);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        /* Clean up */
        cursor.close();

        /* Refresh the listview with the loaded friends */
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: try to write order by in small. becoz this is working perfect in my case

Comment: The Order by is generated, I just pass it the column and ASC. That parameter is for 'order by'

Comment: @user2009 you'll get your result

Comment: Are you sure its the order that they were entered into the db? 

I have a table that orders by text and to get it work I had to create it with these options:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Audits(
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     Name TEXT COLLATE NOCASE)

Comment: My code is working now. Not sure what happend, maybe some glitch. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code my above question is working as expected.